# Are coherent modules with integrable log-connections locally free?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, connections, log-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth Noetherian scheme over a field $K$. It is known that every coherent module with integrable connection on $X$ is locally free.

Is the same true for coherent modules with log-integrable connection with respect to a normal crossing divisor on $X$?

Comment: No, e.g. the structure sheaf of a component of the divisor is a quotient of $\mathcal{O}_X$ in the category of log connections, because its ideal is preserved by log derivations.